# How to use positive lookbehind with If-Then-Else regex in Python

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to combine a positive lookbehind with the If-Then-Else syntax for regex in Python.

What I'm trying to do is parse through some data and I need to use two different markers to split the string.

An example of what I'm trying to do: 
If `data = "(I want) some ice cream"`. Then I want to split the string up after `(I want)`.
At the same time, I might get `data = "I want some ice cream"`. In which case, I want to split the string up after `I`.

The problem I'm facing is that I can't use the first white space as a for-sure way of finding where to separate because there's a white space in `(I want)`.

Using concepts from here http://www.regular-expressions.info/conditional.html, I want to create a If-Then-Else regex with a lookbehind on whether the string starts with `(` or not.

Here's what I have so far:

```
(?(?<=(^\())(^(.*?)\)|^(.*?)( ))
```

If string starts with `"("`, then match until the first `)`. Else match until the first space.
This doesn't work, however.

Answer (score 1):

> If string starts with `(` then match until the first `)`. Else match until the first space. This doesn't work..

I really see no need to use the `If`-`Then`-`Else` conditional here, you could do something like this.

```
^((?:\([^)]*\)|\S+))
```

Regular expression:

```
^              the beginning of the string
(              group and capture to \1:
 (?:           group, but do not capture:
  \(           '('
  [^)]*        any character except: ')' (0 or more times)
  \)           ')'
   |           OR
   \S+         non-whitespace (all but \n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") 
  )            end of grouping
 )             end of \1
```

See [`Live demo`](http://regex101.com/r/mR3bF1)

Answer (score 1):

Your assertion is misplaced here because you haven't actuall moved over the first parenthesis.  Something like this is more appropriate.

```
 # ^((?:\([^)]*\)|\S*))


 ^ 
 (                             # (1)
      (?:
           \( [^)]* \)
        |  \S* 
      )
 )
```

Since it is at the beginning of the string that is in question, if it were a conditional it should be  a lookahead assertion condition.

```
 #  ^((?(?=\()\([^)]*\)|\S*))

      ^ 
 1    (
 c         (?(?= \( )
                \( [^)]* \)    # yes, its a parenth, match '(..)'
             |  
                \S*            # no, match until first space
           )
 1    )
```

For @hwnd. I liked your commented regex I wanted to see it via RegexFormat app.
(Looks good!!)

```
 ^                # the beginning of the string
 (                # (1 start), group and capture to \1:
      (?:              # group, but do not capture:
           \(               # '('
           [^)]*            # any character except: ')' (0 or more times)
           \)               # ')'
        |                   # OR
           \S+              # non-whitespace (all but \n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") 
      )                # end of grouping
 )                # (1 end), end of \1
```

Comment: I couldn't tell if he wanted to actually split the string or match it?

Comment: `two different markers to split the string` haha, I can't either. Most questions are ambiguous.

Comment: I was curious if he meant splitting the matching up into two markers, something like this.. [regex101](http://regex101.com/r/zS7hY6)

Comment: @hwnd - I know what you mean. I clicked the link, but unfortunately it doesn't support <= IE9. I'm still on ie6 (which is a problem).

Comment: Hehe, I cheat with that app. http://www.regexformat.com , its only 20 bucks or so.

Comment: Thanks alot for the help. Clarified some concepts for me.